# Interpret Apple crash report for

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios5.1

My app got rejected by Appl App Store review team becase it was crashed on iPhone 4S and iPad (3rd Gen) running iOS 5.1.1, as soon as the app lunches, as they said.
I tried this app on an iPhone 4 running iOS 5.1.1 and it ran just fine.
They've attached a creadh report that I have no idea hot to investigate and will apreciate if you can help:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   iEC2CDV1.6Lite                          0x00012c24 0x1000 + 72740
1   SystemConfiguration                     0x36d7fce4 0x36d6b000 + 85220
2   CoreFoundation                          0x32c53acc 0x32bc6000 + 580300
3   CoreFoundation                          0x32c5332e 0x32bc6000 + 578350
4   CoreFoundation                          0x32c5203e 0x32bc6000 + 573502
5   CoreFoundation                          0x32bd549e 0x32bc6000 + 62622
6   CoreFoundation                          0x32bd5366 0x32bc6000 + 62310
7   GraphicsServices                        0x32d22432 0x32d1e000 + 17458
8   UIKit                                   0x351b4cce 0x35183000 + 203982
9   iEC2CDV1.6Lite                          0x000030f6 0x1000 + 8438
10  iEC2CDV1.6Lite                          0x000030b4 0x1000 + 8372


Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x351463a8 0x35145000 + 5032
1   libdispatch.dylib                       0x313aaf04 0x313a7000 + 16132
2   libdispatch.dylib                       0x313aac22 0x313a7000 + 15394


Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x35156cd4 0x35145000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x32037f36 0x3202f000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x32037cc8 0x3202f000 + 36040


Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x35156cd4 0x35145000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x32037f36 0x3202f000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x32037cc8 0x3202f000 + 36040


Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x351560d8 0x35145000 + 69848
1   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x32031674 0x3202f000 + 9844
2   WebCore                                 0x358d04e8 0x358ca000 + 25832
3   WebCore                                 0x358d07ec 0x358ca000 + 26604
4   CoreFoundation                          0x32c53b14 0x32bc6000 + 580372
5   CoreFoundation                          0x32c51d50 0x32bc6000 + 572752
6   CoreFoundation                          0x32c5216a 0x32bc6000 + 573802
7   CoreFoundation                          0x32bd549e 0x32bc6000 + 62622
8   CoreFoundation                          0x32bd5366 0x32bc6000 + 62310
9   WebCore                                 0x35973c9c 0x358ca000 + 695452
10  libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3203d72e 0x3202f000 + 59182
11  libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3203d5e8 0x3202f000 + 58856


Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x35146004 0x35145000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x351461fa 0x35145000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                          0x32c533ec 0x32bc6000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                          0x32c52124 0x32bc6000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                          0x32bd549e 0x32bc6000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                          0x32bd5366 0x32bc6000 + 62310
6   Foundation                              0x372d3bb2 0x372c3000 + 68530
7   Foundation                              0x372d3a7a 0x372c3000 + 68218
8   Foundation                              0x3736758a 0x372c3000 + 673162
9   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3203d72e 0x3202f000 + 59182
10  libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3203d5e8 0x3202f000 + 58856


Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x35156cd4 0x35145000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x32037f36 0x3202f000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x32037cc8 0x3202f000 + 36040


Thread 7 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x35146004 0x35145000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x351461fa 0x35145000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                          0x32c533ec 0x32bc6000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                          0x32c52124 0x32bc6000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                          0x32bd549e 0x32bc6000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                          0x32bd5366 0x32bc6000 + 62310
6   WebCore                                 0x3599d0d2 0x358ca000 + 864466
7   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3203d72e 0x3202f000 + 59182
8   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3203d5e8 0x3202f000 + 58856


Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x35156cd4 0x35145000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x32037f36 0x3202f000 + 36662
2   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x32037cc8 0x3202f000 + 36040


Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x35156570 0x35145000 + 71024
1   CoreFoundation                          0x32c5763a 0x32bc6000 + 595514
2   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3203d72e 0x3202f000 + 59182
3   libsystem_c.dylib                       0x3203d5e8 0x3202f000 + 58856


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00279700    r1: 0x00000002      r2: 0x0027dad0      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00279700    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x0002c36e      r7: 0x2fdfef1c
    r8: 0x0027dad0    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x36d99b53     r11: 0x36d99b53
    ip: 0x00279718    sp: 0x2fdfec80      lr: 0x36d7fceb      pc: 0x00012c24
  cpsr: 0x60000010


Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x8dfff +iEC2CDV1.6Lite armv7  &lt;448620039bac30df9ca671e0ececa529&gt; /var/mobile/Applications/C69FF164-19D9-4F4F-A0BA-86F047FA1E1E/iEC2CDV1.6Lite.ap p/iEC2CDV1.6Lite
0x2fe84000 - 0x2fea5fff  dyld armv7  &lt;77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08&gt; /usr/lib/dyld
0x30290000 - 0x3029bfff  AccountSettings armv7  &lt;373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x3029c000 - 0x3032efff  HomeSharing armv7  &lt;11ca6ed6f8c0377aba1d3e03484c380f&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x303e9000 - 0x3042efff  GeoServices armv7  &lt;a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x3042f000 - 0x3049ffff  CoreImage armv7  &lt;86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x304b9000 - 0x30588fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  &lt;49607ffe4ee9389494285a213e392924&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x30589000 - 0x3058afff  CoreSurface armv7  &lt;97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x30597000 - 0x305f4fff  StoreServices armv7  &lt;6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x305f5000 - 0x305f5fff  Accelerate armv7  &lt;55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x30608000 - 0x30619fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  &lt;ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505&gt; /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3061a000 - 0x3062bfff  AirTraffic armv7  &lt;c9eb888c1bd1322cbda5b01d41be0c7d&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x30632000 - 0x306b1fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  &lt;bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416&gt; /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x306b2000 - 0x306e9fff  Security armv7  &lt;eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30844000 - 0x30880fff  AppSupport armv7  &lt;311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x3088a000 - 0x30890fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  &lt;aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475&gt; /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x30891000 - 0x30891fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  &lt;ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960&gt; /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3089f000 - 0x30a45fff  CoreData armv7  &lt;b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x30a48000 - 0x30b4efff  IMGSGX543GLDriver armv7  &lt;7454a840600038949d67edad05097242&gt; /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver
0x30bb1000 - 0x30bc0fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  &lt;70ac33720f513f0f97ea2279260678ca&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x30bc1000 - 0x30bd5fff  PersistentConnection armv7  &lt;54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConn ection
0x30bd6000 - 0x30beefff  iAd armv7  &lt;9e9184ed0077317a97b879c3df950316&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
0x30bfe000 - 0x30c72fff  MediaControlSender armv7  &lt;87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSend er
0x30c73000 - 0x30c77fff  CertUI armv7  &lt;f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x30d92000 - 0x30dcefff  iCalendar armv7  &lt;f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x30dcf000 - 0x30e04fff  DataAccess armv7  &lt;89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x30e05000 - 0x30e06fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  &lt;6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a&gt; /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x30e07000 - 0x30f7afff  MediaPlayer armv7  &lt;63cdf8f9c66d36e7a4e69e2f6cae854f&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x3102a000 - 0x31082fff  CoreAudio armv7  &lt;be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31083000 - 0x31092fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  &lt;d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalSto rage
0x31096000 - 0x311cdfff  MusicLibrary armv7  &lt;32bc794969e534df97a14dc4be228408&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x3121c000 - 0x312fbfff  RawCamera armv7  &lt;293f818ba6533dceae8b900b6ed3c887&gt; /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x312fc000 - 0x31314fff  Notes armv7  &lt;724966ed5cd4395cb70f9c996b123f53&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x31315000 - 0x31317fff  MobileInstallation armv7  &lt;215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallati on
0x313a7000 - 0x313bdfff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  &lt;9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78&gt; /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x313f2000 - 0x313f6fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  &lt;9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572&gt; /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x313f7000 - 0x3141cfff  OpenCL armv7  &lt;f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x3144d000 - 0x3144efff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  &lt;9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907&gt; /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3148a000 - 0x3154cfff  Celestial armv7  &lt;19617260ee073e23b95e456d93930aea&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x315c0000 - 0x315ddfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  &lt;50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9&gt; /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x315de000 - 0x315effff  DataAccessExpress armv7  &lt;e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x3161a000 - 0x316cdfff  iTunesStore armv7  &lt;b3c0cce5f8e632e18f841c32b68f57a1&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x31a99000 - 0x31a99fff  vecLib armv7  &lt;a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vec Lib
0x31c18000 - 0x31ccefff  AVFoundation armv7  &lt;35cb7a0eb1dc3554a777c1cc11cb0415&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x31e1d000 - 0x31e1ffff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  &lt;d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x31e22000 - 0x31e22fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  &lt;e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005&gt; /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x31e23000 - 0x31e26fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  &lt;f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31e27000 - 0x31e3afff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  &lt;3f4596cbe1b13fdcb427d87de21df3f6&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x31e3e000 - 0x31e55fff  WebBookmarks armv7  &lt;696bb0630b19388da0d72e685bcf6e28&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x31ec4000 - 0x31ecbfff  MailServices armv7  &lt;ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x31ecc000 - 0x31ed1fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  &lt;52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2&gt; /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x31fe1000 - 0x3202bfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  &lt;f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfigu ration
0x3202f000 - 0x320bbfff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  &lt;f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697&gt; /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x320bc000 - 0x320befff  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  &lt;808518e0fbf539af8489f028ca5198c7&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x320bf000 - 0x320c0fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  &lt;9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498&gt; /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x320c8000 - 0x321b9fff  QuartzCore armv7  &lt;35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x323de000 - 0x3248bfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  &lt;58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1&gt; /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3248c000 - 0x3248dfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  &lt;402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c&gt; /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x324c5000 - 0x324c5fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  &lt;644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8&gt; /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3275b000 - 0x327a5fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  &lt;441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/lib vDSP.dylib
0x32804000 - 0x32808fff  Marco armv7  &lt;8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x3280c000 - 0x32892fff  CoreMotion armv7  &lt;6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x32893000 - 0x32981fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  &lt;2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2&gt; /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3298a000 - 0x329d8fff  CoreLocation armv7  &lt;44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x32a2b000 - 0x32a34fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  &lt;4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42&gt; /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x32b14000 - 0x32b40fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  &lt;3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf&gt; /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x32bc6000 - 0x32cddfff  CoreFoundation armv7  &lt;6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x32d06000 - 0x32d0afff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  &lt;42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebu ffer
0x32d1e000 - 0x32d28fff  GraphicsServices armv7  &lt;cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x32d2c000 - 0x32fedfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  &lt;0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/lib LAPACK.dylib
0x33497000 - 0x334e0fff  AddressBook armv7  &lt;b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x335af000 - 0x335b7fff  MobileWiFi armv7  &lt;b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x335c2000 - 0x335d8fff  libmis.dylib armv7  &lt;258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807&gt; /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x335d9000 - 0x335f8fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  &lt;0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c&gt; /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x335f9000 - 0x335fefff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  &lt;27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93&gt; /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x335ff000 - 0x3363bfff  IMFoundation armv7  &lt;253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.fram ework/IMFoundation
0x336f6000 - 0x336fbfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  &lt;dc11c5c2cbe73a6288a6094ebf5de673&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterS upport
0x336fc000 - 0x33702fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  &lt;9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800&gt; /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x33704000 - 0x33768fff  MessageUI armv7  &lt;da7af4f9494b35558bf7892dfdb36ee3&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x337f6000 - 0x33a23fff  MediaToolbox armv7  &lt;c3098478486032c6aff336fa711c4fc6&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x33a45000 - 0x33aeffff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  &lt;bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/lib BLAS.dylib
0x33b12000 - 0x33c57fff  CoreGraphics armv7  &lt;903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x33c5a000 - 0x33cbdfff  IMCore armv7  &lt;046b6b615a743057b59d4aaba8a91d61&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x33df4000 - 0x33dfbfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  &lt;bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045&gt; /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x33e16000 - 0x33e19fff  CoreTime armv7  &lt;a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x33e1a000 - 0x33e27fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  &lt;750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8&gt; /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x33e64000 - 0x33eb5fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  &lt;c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793&gt; /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33eb6000 - 0x33ec8fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  &lt;50ea319aaeb7307e92719980dd4b2953&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x33f6f000 - 0x33f98fff  AppleAccount armv7  &lt;2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x33fc4000 - 0x33fc4fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  &lt;a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x33fca000 - 0x34070fff  AddressBookUI armv7  &lt;da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x34071000 - 0x34091fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  &lt;39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456&gt; /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x34095000 - 0x3416dfff  vImage armv7  &lt;caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vIm age
0x3417b000 - 0x34181fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  &lt;9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53&gt; /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x34182000 - 0x34188fff  IAP armv7  &lt;17eddbf5590d3cb88d4acbda27447f5b&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x34194000 - 0x3419cfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  &lt;0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x345ab000 - 0x34aeffff  FaceCoreLight armv7  &lt;f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x34af0000 - 0x34b06fff  DictionaryServices armv7  &lt;6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServic es
0x34c1b000 - 0x34ce1fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  &lt;90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416&gt; /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34d0d000 - 0x34d13fff  MobileIcons armv7  &lt;ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x34d14000 - 0x34d1efff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  &lt;40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1&gt; /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x34d20000 - 0x34d20fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  &lt;eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d&gt; /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x34d25000 - 0x34d6dfff  CoreMedia armv7  &lt;e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x34d6e000 - 0x34d75fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  &lt;38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibrary Services
0x34d76000 - 0x34d79fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  &lt;7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x34e4a000 - 0x34e9bfff  CoreText armv7  &lt;5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x34eba000 - 0x34f80fff  GLEngine armv7  &lt;6617f2b4ee283469a5595129889ff049&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x34f81000 - 0x34f9afff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  &lt;1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x34f9b000 - 0x34fd9fff  IOKit armv7  &lt;fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x34fda000 - 0x34fdefff  IOSurface armv7  &lt;443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35145000 - 0x3515bfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  &lt;311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a&gt; /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3515c000 - 0x35172fff  EAP8021X armv7  &lt;952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35173000 - 0x3517dfff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  &lt;e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/lib vMisc.dylib
0x35183000 - 0x35625fff  UIKit armv7  &lt;cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x35787000 - 0x357cafff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  &lt;95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26&gt; /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x357fa000 - 0x35809fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  &lt;a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServ ices
0x3580a000 - 0x3580efff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  &lt;998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x358ca000 - 0x36089fff  WebCore armv7  &lt;2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3608a000 - 0x3615afff  WebKit armv7  &lt;3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3615b000 - 0x361a7fff  CoreTelephony armv7  &lt;b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x361b7000 - 0x361fbfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  &lt;757226927a873d5492be721908077b48&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x361ff000 - 0x36202fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  &lt;356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc&gt; /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x36203000 - 0x3624cfff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  &lt;5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4&gt; /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x3625e000 - 0x36296fff  VideoToolbox armv7  &lt;9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x36297000 - 0x363bcfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  &lt;2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x36942000 - 0x36a19fff  CFNetwork armv7  &lt;765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36a1a000 - 0x36a1bfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  &lt;977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab&gt; /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x36a1c000 - 0x36a23fff  MediaRemote armv7  &lt;42dc1b43dabd3692b97d6aacfbdf0449&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x36a98000 - 0x36b11fff  ProofReader armv7  &lt;6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x36b49000 - 0x36b88fff  QuickLook armv7  &lt;802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x36b89000 - 0x36d46fff  ImageIO armv7  &lt;02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x36d47000 - 0x36d6afff  Bom armv7  &lt;c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x36d6b000 - 0x36da0fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  &lt;4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x36f91000 - 0x37175fff  AudioToolbox armv7  &lt;c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3720b000 - 0x3723ffff  MIME armv7  &lt;d30292ea8f7e360fa5f5d5b1b62b602d&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x372a8000 - 0x372b4fff  CoreVideo armv7  &lt;364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x372c3000 - 0x37441fff  Foundation armv7  &lt;c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x374b1000 - 0x374eefff  FTServices armv7  &lt;3f23418319a03a589dd5cac7df20e238&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x37615000 - 0x37618fff  ActorKit armv7  &lt;434c756a6b053f4ba3c954cfccddbf59&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x3762b000 - 0x376c4fff  EventKit armv7  &lt;d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x376f1000 - 0x376f4fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  &lt;b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187&gt; /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x37783000 - 0x37787fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  &lt;3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictio nary
0x3781d000 - 0x3781efff  DataMigration armv7  &lt;d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3781f000 - 0x3785ffff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  &lt;40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x37965000 - 0x3796bfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  &lt;e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x379c0000 - 0x379c5fff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  &lt;3c1cc3175c403ace8fcbd3826bd43807&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dyl ib
0x379c6000 - 0x379c9fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  &lt;e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777&gt; /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x379ca000 - 0x379d6fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  &lt;bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a&gt; /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x379d7000 - 0x37a12fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  &lt;55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16&gt; /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dyl ib
0x37a39000 - 0x37a3dfff  libcache.dylib armv7  &lt;d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882&gt; /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x37af4000 - 0x37b24fff  ContentIndex armv7  &lt;7a64670bb2ff3ee39ddee1dc1c72f92d&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x37b25000 - 0x37b3afff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  &lt;66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb&gt; /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x37b3b000 - 0x37b3ffff  FTClientServices armv7  &lt;21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x37b40000 - 0x37c89fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  &lt;b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1&gt; /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x37c8a000 - 0x37cadfff  MobileSync armv7  &lt;e42604c550283f4aa517ae8f108b340f&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x37ccb000 - 0x37ceffff  PrintKit armv7  &lt;08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x37cf0000 - 0x37cf5fff  ApplePushService armv7  &lt;f424c0340de637c08bbeb4f3bd8c6eaf&gt; /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x37d60000 - 0x37d6cfff  li
```

Comment: I suppose you are doing manual memory management? If that is the case, try to take a look at this link. Are you over releasing objects? http://www.andrashatvani.com/2011/05/understanding-excbadaccess.html

Comment: Thanks Paul! ACtually I'm using [this Admob plugin for Phonegap](https://github.com/smithimage/phonegap-plugins/commit/2abbc28605e7266c5a2aadb9eeff51b416eb403a), and this is the source of the problem (Another version of the app without this plugin was just fine). The problem is that I'm not sure what exactly is the problem with the plugin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Crash Logs without Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html).

Comment: Crash logs for iOS and Mac OS X are basically identical with only minor differences. You must symbolicate the crash report using Xcode and the organizer. Simply import the crash report into the organizer device logs and hope you have all data available that is required to get it symbolicated. That is the exact binary that produced the crash and a so called dSYM file for that exact binary. Usually both are available in the organizer Archives tab. Not sure if this is also the case when using Phonegap to build apps.

Comment: When I drag and drop the attached .plist file from apple's response nothing happening. Is this because I don't have these files in the Xcode archive?

Comment: Open the organizer, select "Devices", select "Device Logs", click the "Import" button on the bottom, select the crash report, not the .plist file but the .crash file! See what happens.

Comment: Thank you Kerni! I already spotted the problem (wrong SDK version) - but your tip is very useful.