# How to use Admob Phonegap plugin with iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, admob

I'm using [this Admob plugin for Phonegap](https://github.com/smithimage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/AdMob) running on iOS like this:

```
window.plugins.AdMob.createBanner({"siteId":"my-site-id"});
window.plugins.AdMob.loadBanner();
// move banner to make it appear
window.plugins.AdMob.moveBanner({"positionX":0,"positionY":410});
```

And it's actually working. The problem is that this is causing my app to consume a lot memory, and the app to crush when on a device according to the Apple crash report I got from iTunesConnect.

Can you help me in understanding how to use this plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know where your app is consuming a lot of memory? Do you have any of the crash reports and/or stack traces to show us? These would help in identifying the problem.

Comment: Please see the crash report [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667385/interpret-apple-crash-report-for#comment13857116_10667385)

Comment: How do you figure out the parameters for the AdMob methods? Any reference would be much appreciated, thank!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the deletBanner: method anywhere? I think there may be a memory leak there possibly. The plugin looks like it removes the adBanner property from its superview and nil's it out, but I think it may need to also:

- Set the `delegate` for `adBanner` to `nil`
- Release the `adBanner` (you can double-check this by seeing what the retain count of the `adBanner` is). I think UIViewController's `dealloc` automatically calls `removeFromSuperView`: but `deleteBanner`: probably wouldn't do that?

Comment: I believe you are right, and the correct usage might be like this
`// First delete banner if exsist in any of the html pages    
window.plugins.AdMob.deleteBanner();    
window.plugins.AdMob.createBanner({"siteId":"my-site-id"});    
window.plugins.AdMob.loadBanner();    
// move banner to make it appear    
window.plugins.AdMob.moveBanner({"positionX":0,"positionY":410});`    
What do you think?

Comment: OK, so using the `deleteBanner` method as is didn't work, the app continued to crush at startup. I now added this `self.adBanner.delegate = nil;
[self.adBanner release];` to AdMobController.m. Hopefully it will work,